# Change another class' property through property changed in MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

My previous similarly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093142/how-to-change-data-in-every-item-in-observablecollection) was answered through using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. However, researches taught me that inheriting `ViewModelBase` from [GalaSoft.MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs) is similar with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I was using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58094333/12046859) from my question in changing data in every item in `ObservableCollection`. But I don't want use `INotifyPropertyChanged` anymore since I am already inheriting `ViewModelBase`. Codes below are some that I added from the answer I already mentioned:

**Food class**

```
private bool _isAllSelected = true;

public bool IsAllSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _isAllSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(IsAllSelected, ref _isAllSelected, value);
        // send message to viewmodel
        Messenger.Default.Send(Message.message);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
// message handler
private void MsgHandler(Message message)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(SelectAllPropertyName);
}

// the property that change all checkbox of fruits
public const string SelectAllPropertyName = "SelectAll";

public bool SelectAll
{
    set
    {
        bool isAllSelected = Foods.Select(c => c.IsAllSelected).Any();
        foreach (var item in Foods.SelectMany(c => c.Fruits).ToList())
        {
            item.IsSelected = isAllSelected;
        }
    }
}

// receives message function, called at the start
public void Receiver()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<Message>(this, MsgHandler);
}
```

Problem here is this is not working like it was previously using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: where do you receive your message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993918/mvvm-light-messenger-sending-and-registering-objects

Comment: I have a function that receives the message. See edit

Comment: When is you receiver method called? if this method is never call, you will never subscribe to this event. is this method really called as expected?

Comment: Certainly called as what mentioned.

Comment: Foods is an ObservableCollection ? IsSelected is also using the INotifyPropChanged system?

Comment: Yes and Sort of. Yes, food is ObservableCollection and sort of because `Mvvmlight` has `RaisePropertyChanged` which I believe is the same.

Comment: try to implement your IsSelected  proprety explicitly private bool _isSelected; public bool IsSelected {get.... set....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned that you are using [the answer from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093142/how-to-change-data-in-every-item-in-observablecollection/58094333#58094333) and also this *"I don't want use INotifyPropertyChanged anymore since I am already inheriting ViewModelBase"* from this question.

You can actually remove the inheritance of `INotifyPropertyChanged` from your `Fruit` class (refer to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093142/how-to-change-data-in-every-item-in-observablecollection/58094333#58094333)), as you can still use `PropertyChangedEventHandler` as long as you are using `System.ComponentModel` in your class `usings`.

So basically, this will be the only change from your previous question's answer code:

```
public class Fruit : ViewModelBase
{
    ....
}
```